# How to align cell editor vertically center in ExtJS editable grid?

Tags: css, extjs

I have an editable ExtJS grid, whose 1st row has more height then other rows. The editor is defined for every column based on datatypes. As first row's height is more than the other rows and editor is common, neither I am not able to provide the extra padding on cell-editor in first row only.
[As shown here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ENkp.png)